# MediaScannerConnection for AS3/AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, import

import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient;

These are classes available in Java to refresh the detected images on an SD card on an Android device.

If you save an image to the SD card, it's there, but not visible unless you mount the device, unmount the device. These Java classes fix that problem.

But I'm building an App using AS3 and AIR, does anyone know the equivalent classes for AIR, AS3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adobe Air's File class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) to poke around the device (also cf., [Working with Files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d8e.html)).  Once you figure out what code gets you to the USB device, you can load it as a `ByteArray` and convert that to an image.

If you are looking for image import/conversion code, just search for what you need; there are numerous posts out there, and the answers are fairly standardized.